# Retaining textbox value in jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox

In the following code every time button is clicked the alter shows the value of the variable counter=20 which is the value of null text box. 
Kindly guide regarding this.

```
 var username = $("#<%= uname.ClientID %>").val();
 var pwd = $("#<%= pwd.ClientID %>").val();

 var counter = (function () {
            var counter1 = 0;
            return function () {

                if (username == "DEF" && pwd == "5678") {
                    counter1 = 6;
                }

                else if (username == "" && pwd == "") {
                    counter1 = 20;
                }

                else {
                    counter1 = -1;
                }

                return counter1;
            };
            return false;
        })();




        $("#<%= Login.ClientID %>").click(function makecounter1() {


            counter();

            if (counter() != -1) {

                alert(counter());

            }

            else {
                alert("Wrong Credentials");
            }



            return false;


        });
```

Why counter doesn't show other value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are set when the page is loaded and is not getting refreshed.

move the code

```
 var username = $("#<%= uname.ClientID %>").val();
 var pwd = $("#<%= pwd.ClientID %>").val();
```

into the function `counter` and it should work.